# Resize performance related to Ticks/Frame presence in Graphics

Tags: performance-tuning, front-end, windows

*EDIT* With Halirutan's help I have now a minimal example that exhibits the problem on every Windows machine I have.

I have an OS/software specific problem with performance:

[image]

The left one is smooth and the right one jumps. It is a minimal example, for the real case it becomes unbearable.

```
ticks = Table[x, {x, -1, 1, .05}];
g1 = Graphics[Circle[], Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Full, 
   AspectRatio -> Full, 
   FrameTicks -> {{ticks, ticks}, {ticks, ticks}}];
g2 = Graphics[Circle[], Frame -> False, ImageSize -> Full, 
   AspectRatio -> Full];
resizeArea = 
  Framed@Pane[#, AppearanceElements -> "ResizeArea", 
     ImageSize -> 100 {1, 1/GoldenRatio}, FrameMargins -> 15] &;

{resizeArea[g1], resizeArea[g2]}
```

#### reproduced in:

- V10.4-11.2 Win10 (GeForce GT 630)
- V10.4-11.2 Win7 (GeForce GT 960)

#### not reproduced in:

- virtual machine macOS High Sierra V11.2 (GeForce GT 630)

  It is was slower but not as laggy.

For virtual machine it works so it seems it is not a hardware issue ( I can provide details about spec if needed though)

What could be the reason? Can you reproduce this?

WRI Support failed to reproduce the problem so I'm stuck with this until I can narrow the specs down.

Comment: it is smooth in my iMac (Intel i3 3.06GHz, 12GB RAM, ATI Radeon HD 4670 256Mb) with macOS 10.13.3, and MMA 11.2

Comment: all okay with minimal example using V11.2 on OSX 10.11.6

Comment: I can reproduce on version 11.2, Windows 10, AMD FirePro M4150